# Loading unpacked extensions error when running Protractor E2E tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

After some recently rolled out policy updates with Chrome, we are now experiencing the unpacked extension issue when running Protractor E2E tests with Selenium Web Driver.

The error is:

```
Failed to load extension from:C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9090_11922\internal.
```

Loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator.

This internal folder was unziped from internal.zip, and contains the following `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSI...",
  "name": "Chrome Automation Extension",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Exposes extension APIs for automating Chrome",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
     "tabs", "management", "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

In the *protractor config* file we tried to disable extensions here, but it had no effect:

```json
multiCapabilities: [        
         {
             browserName: 'chrome',
             chromeOptions: {
                 args: [
                     '--disable-extensions', '--disable-plugins', '--start-maximized'
                 ]
             }
         },
    ]
```

As per [comment 22 on March 31st](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324#c22) in [this Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=604324), they introduced a new Chrome option, `--useAutomationExtension`. So as soon as I get Protractor working again on my box, I will try it as follows:

```json
chromeOptions: {
    args: [
          '--disable-extensions', '--disable-plugins', '--start-maximized',
          '--useAutomationExtension=false'
    ]
}
```

#### My primary question is:

Has anyone pinpointed exactly the extension name which is unpacked, and what to communicate to their IT department for whitelist purposes?
[Here is an old post which addresses this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639).

#### In addition:

1. Has anyone successfully implemented the `--useAutomationExtension=false` option in *protractor.conf.js*?

I will update this post as I progress throughout the day, hoping to add some clarity.

Answer (score 5):

The error can be solved with the following chromeOptions in  protractor.conf.js :

**1. Disable AutomationExtension**

```
chromeOptions: {
  useAutomationExtension: false
}
```

**2. Run Chrome in headless mode (without UI)**

```
chromeOptions: {
 args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
}
```

Which is faster but you will not see anything

Comment: @bob.mazzo: did you find a solution for it? please can you share. I am having similar issue.

Comment: i have to same problem. I want to see the chome and don't want to run headless. what should i do?

Comment: Just the first bit "useAutomationExtension: false" did the trick for me :)

Comment: For me, only the "--headless" does the trick, useAutomationExtension seems to have no effect

Comment: I have same problem , 'useAutomationExtension' : false not working for me. Any other way to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same problem in 2020 with recent versions of node and @angular, under Ubuntu 20.4.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 12.18.2
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.0.7
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.0
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.0
@schematics/angular               9.0.7
@schematics/update                0.900.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.43.0
```

The above instructions to put 'useAutomationExtension: false' in the chromeOptions section of protractor.conf.js worked for me.

However, '--headless' will not fix this problem because the error message, while a bit cryptic, is telling the truth. Thus, setting a 'headless' option just causes the test to time out because the error displays in a popup and it requires one to click the 'ok' button in order to continue the test.

Unless you have a dev channel version of chromium, the automation extension is not in your browser. So chrome driver by default is trying to use an extension that isn't available on non-dev-channel versions of chromium.

> Availability: Dev channel only. Learn more.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/automation

Personally, I think this is crazy. The driver should check to see if this extension is available before attempting to use it. I have seen many posts on this subject and not one seems to have hit on the real issue. The answer above will solve the problem, but the root of this is that chrome driver's assumption is that the extension is always there. Thus, testing against a 'real world browser version' (Most users are not downloading dev-channel versions of chromium) - which should be the default - is the exception.